# mysql filtering result using left outer join

Tags: mysql, database, filter, left-join

my query:

```
        SELECT content.*, activity_log.content_id FROM content
        LEFT JOIN activity_log 
        ON content.id = activity_log.content_id 
        AND sess_id = '$sess_id'
        WHERE activity_log.content_id IS NULL
        AND visibility = $visibility
        AND content.reported < ".REPORTED_LIMIT."
        AND content.file_ready = 1
        LIMIT 1
```

The purpose of that query is to get 1 row from the content table that has not been viewed by the user (identified by session_id), but it still returns contents that have been viewed. What is wrong? ( I have checked the table making sure that the content_ids are there)

Note: I think this is more efficient than using subqueries, thoughts?

Comment: Yes, in MySQL (atleast 5.0 and below) this is more efficient than using subqueries.

I don't see why the query doesn't work though.

Comment: What is the point of returning `activity_log.content_id` in the SELECT when you have said in the WHERE clause that it must be NULL?

Comment: If `activity_log.content_id` nullable?

Comment: @WoLpH what's the difference if I use mysql and higher? Has there been a change in the way it processes subqueries?

Comment: I would still use an outer join instead of a subquery in more recent versions of MySQL.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your query.  I suggest you double-check that you're seeing wrong results.  Can you edit your question and add an example?

Comment: @user288178: I don't know if a newer version of MySQL has improved the query planner enough to make it automatically rewrite subqueries so I can't guarantee that :) I do know that with the older versions it didn't. Either way, the `LEFT JOIN` is definately the better method.

Comment: @everyone:it's not the query, something else is interfering with the result, sorry for the confusion :(

Answer (score 1):

The problem is obviously in your JOIN condition. The optimization you are using (applying a condition to the base table) makes sense when you are interested in inner join results, but in case of an outer JOIN this is read as following: find correspondences between `content` and `activity_log` rows when the content id matches and session id matches, and return nulls for `activity_log` rows when either logs for the content id is missing, or content id is not missing, but the *session id is not the one specified*. And it is hardly what you want.

Your query should should look like this:

```
SELECT content.*, activity_log.content_id
FROM (
SELECT *
FROM content
WHERE sess_id = '$sess_id'
    AND visibility = $visibility
    AND file_ready = 1
    AND reported < ".REPORTED_LIMIT."
) as content
LEFT JOIN activity_log 
ON content.id = activity_log.content_id 
WHERE activity_log.content_id IS NULL
LIMIT 1;
```

If the performance is not optimal, you can consider creating a composite index on (sess_id, visibility, fileready, reported).